# Get size of uncompressed gzip file while size of compressed file is available from server

Tags: java, android, gzip

I am using `GZIPInputStream` to download PDF file. I want to show the download progress of the file on a UI button. But, I am not getting the actual size of the file, what I am getting is compressed size due to which I am unable to show the correct download progress. This download progress is exceeding `100` as the actual file size is greater than the compressed size of file.

Header content of file from server: Following info I receive from server, from which I am using `content-length` which is giving compressed file size.

```
1.Connection
2.Content-Encoding
3.Content-length
4.Content-Type
5.Keep-Alive
6.Server
7.Date
```

Here is my code. Is there any way to get original size of file?

```
long fileLength =  httpResponse.getEntity().getContentLength();//
GZIPInputStream input = new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
        httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destinationFilePath);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
float percentage = 0;
int count;
currentDownloadingPercentage=0;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    output.write(data, 0, count);

    // publishing the progress....
    percentage = (float)total/(float)fileLength;
    percentage *= 100;
    if ((int)percentage > (int)currentDownloadingPercentage) {
        currentDownloadingPercentage = percentage;
        Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
        resultData.putBoolean(DOWNLOAD_FAILED, false);
        resultData.putInt(DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS ,(int)percentage);
        receiver.send(processID, resultData);
        resultData = null;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at it the wrong way. You should be counting the compressed bytes that you read and calculating the progress based on those. Instead, you're counting the decompressed bytes and comparing it with the compressed file size. In answer to your question, there's no (reliable) way to determine the size of a gzipped file without decompressing it.

**Update:** Here's one way you could count the uncompressed bytes coming in. Wrap the raw input stream with a [`TeeInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) before wrapping it with the GZIPInputStream. Make the TeeInputStream branch to a [`CountingOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html). Then you'll always have a current count of the compressed bytes that have been downloaded via [`getByteCount()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html#getByteCount%28%29)

Comment: I tried that too by using InputStream, that was working fine on progress part, but the stream was resulting in a compressed file. Decompressing this file was taking more than usual in offline mode. It was taking whole another round for decompressing byte by byte for the file. Below is the code which reads compressed bytes only..InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());

Comment: I've updated my answer with a way to count the compressed bytes on the fly.

Comment: Ryan, how should I do it in android? Any alternative for TeeInputStream in android?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you were on Android. It wouldn't be hard to write your own, and commons-io is open source, so you could just grab the source files from there.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16227) discuss result seems not way to avoid HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() automatically returned GZIPInputStream, once you let HttpURLConnection accept gzip compression, you won't calculate download progress accurately, the only one we can do just disable gzip as acceptable encoding :

```
HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

Another choice is use [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html), I had tested about this, even we present accept gzip encoding like this :

```
HttpUriRequest.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

the InputStream instance that return by **HttpResponse.getEntity().getContent()** will be **EofSensorInputStream**, an original InputStream is what we wanted, isn't GZIPInputStream, that make us possible to wrap it to GZIPInputStream by myself, we can use TeeInputStream and CountingOutputStream to finish calculating download progress.

```
HttpResponse response = ...;
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
long fileSize = entity.getContentLength();

InputStream ins = entity.getContent(); // instance of EofSensorInputStream
CountingOutputStream coStrem = new CountingOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream(100));
GZIPInputStream inStrem = new GZIPInputStream(new TeeInputStream(ins, coStrem, true));

byte[] buffer = new byte[6 * 1024]; // 6K buffer
int offset;

while ((offset = inStrem.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    tmpFileRaf.write(buffer, 0, offset);
    postDownloadProgress(fileSize, coStrem.getByteCount());
}
```

I think that's all we can do with this problem, I tried pick up [android libcore](http://iamkoch.com/2013/11/how-to-get-libcore-sources-for-httpurlconnectionimpl-java-and-other-classes-missing-from-the-base-android-sdks/) source with my project so we can customize **HttpURLConnectionImpl** then suppress it return GZIPInputStream, but many errors makes trouble, I discard this effort.

In this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html), Jesse Wilson suggested we the best choice client of Android is HttpURLConnection, so I'm looking for how to solve this problem always, I hope I can get a way soon.